# How to update the list of dependecies in node module and package.json in Angular

Tags: angular, typescript, dependencies

I have recently received angular src folder from my friend. So i created an Angular project and replaced the created src folder with my friend's src folder. Then, i tried to run the application using npm start, it caused errors since it says there are dependencies need to be installed or not in the node_modules. How to overcome it?

[This is the snippet of the error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FHdoj.png)

Help me to solve the error. I tried every possible way from "npm start", deleting node modules and installing it back.Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Simply way to solve the problem is to take file `package.json` from your friend project, put it on the same level as `src` folder and run `npm install` to install all necessary dependencies, `node_modules` folder will appear automatically.

If you couldn't do it, than create empty document `package.json` on the same level as `src` folder and install all dependencies one by one with command `npm install <package_name>`. Than each package will appear on your package.json file automatically and `node_modules` folder will appear automatically.

- `npm install jsencrypt`
- `npm install @microsoft/microsoft-graph-client`
- etc.

But notice that in second case you install the last version of packages and it could be not the same as in your friend project. Wrong packages versions could trow compatibility error.

Also I see there must be some config file in assets folder `assets/config/config.json` with ApiServerUrl information. By name i understand it could be URL for access back-end and you also need to take it from friend project.

You could read more about package.json file in [Documentation](https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/v9/configuring-npm/package-json)